# Installing Visual Studio 2012 on x64 machine: use x64 build?

Tags: visual-studio

I just got my new MSDN subscription up and running, and was wondering something about when I go to install all my dev tools:  Is there any specific reason I should install Visual Studio x64 over x86?  I'm on an x64 machine, but I can obviously compile to any platform I want no matter what architecture VS is compiled for.  I can't think of any reason VS would be using more than 4GB of RAM.  Is there some sort of special case that necessitates an x64 build of VS?  All I can think is maybe some game development scenarios where the debugger is dealing with huge amounts of memory at once.

Comment: I don't think there is a VS 2012 64bit.. only 32 bit exists AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that there is no 64-bit Visual Studio as [Rico Mariani](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx) explains.  That should not be a big deal because you can specify 32-bit, 64-bit or Any CPU when creating your applications in Visual Studio.